# Is it possible to make a laptop behave as if it is working on battery?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, battery, power

Is it possible to make a laptop behave as if it is working on battery, while in fact it would be working on AC power?

I have some HW problem with my laptop. It reboots for unknown reason every time it is connected to AC Power. I have two external batteries which I switch during my work. While I am working with one battery, another one is re-charging and so on.
I would like to connect the laptop to AC Power, but to "fool" it, so it would "think" it is working on battery and would not reboot. 
My laptop model is HP EliteBook 8760w.

Comment: Maybe there's something funny in your power plan.

Comment: @aparente001, I tried - did not work.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be possible.  Open the `Device Manager` and look for the `Batteries` category.  If its there, expand it and remove all the devices.  This *may* work until you reboot and it autoinstalls those devices again.

Its a slim chance, but it could work.

Comment: It did not work for me. I had 4 devices there: one for Power Adapter, one for the primary battery, one for the secondary battery and one was called "Microsoft Composite Battery". I was able to remove 3 of them, but windows did not let me to remove the Composite Battery. Anyway, it did not have any effect